# Zkteco How to read attendance by log period?

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkteco

How do I use sta_readLogByPeriod code? Here's a Source code from Zkteco but it is not working.

```
string fromTime = stime_log.Text.Trim().ToString();
string toTime = etime_log.Text.Trim().ToString();

DataTable dt_periodLog = new DataTable("dt_periodLog");
gv_Attlog.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gv_Attlog.Columns.Clear();
dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("User ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify Type", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify State", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("WorkCode", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
gv_Attlog.DataSource = dt_periodLog;

DataMng.SDK.sta_readLogByPeriod(DataMng.lbSysOutputInfo, dt_periodLog, fromTime, toTime);
```

---

But I have seen in Github, that i need to Update my Firmware Version But How do I Update my Firmware Version ? [Github Link.](https://github.com/adrobinoga/zk-protocol/blob/master/sections/data-record.md#current-descriptions)

Comment: You may update the firmware on the device.

Comment: @rjs123431 does it possible to update the device via. software? Like ZkAccess 3.5 ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Zkteco Philippines. [image] Look's like we can't do anything about it.

As Zkteco Said :

```
Good Day!
    About this, only us can update firmware and there's a charge to it.
```

Comment: I guess your only option, other than buying new device, is to still use `ReadGeneralLogData` and do a filter inside `while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData....` Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

**1st of all fill all logs to Data table then make the function to fill data table**

```
public int sta_readLogByPeriod( DataTable dt_logPeriod, string fromTime, string toTime)
    {
        zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
        if (axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.1.201",4370) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("*Please connect first!");
            return -1024;
        }
    dt_logPeriod.Columns.Add("User ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt_logPeriod.Columns.Add("Verify Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt_logPeriod.Columns.Add("Verify Type", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dt_logPeriod.Columns.Add("Verify State", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dt_logPeriod.Columns.Add("WorkCode", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

    int ret = 0;

    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(1, false);//disable the device

    string sdwEnrollNumber = "";
    int idwVerifyMode = 0;
    int idwInOutMode = 0;
    int idwYear = 0;
    int idwMonth = 0;
    int idwDay = 0;
    int idwHour = 0;
    int idwMinute = 0;
    int idwSecond = 0;
    int idwWorkcode = 0;


    if (axCZKEM1.ReadTimeGLogData(1, fromTime, toTime))
    {
        while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(1, out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
                    out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode))//get records from the memory
        {
            DataRow dr = dt_logPeriod.NewRow();
            dr["User ID"] = sdwEnrollNumber;
            dr["Verify Date"] = idwYear + "-" + idwMonth + "-" + idwDay + " " + idwHour + ":" + idwMinute + ":" + idwSecond;
            dr["Verify Type"] = idwVerifyMode;
            dr["Verify State"] = idwInOutMode;
            dr["WorkCode"] = idwWorkcode;
            dt_logPeriod.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        ret = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref ret);
        

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("*Read attlog by period failed,ErrorCode: " + ret.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!");
        }
    }


    //lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("[func ReadTimeGLogData]Temporarily unsupported");
    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(1, true);//enable the device

    return ret;
}
```

**Now call function and pass the Datatable**

```
DataTable dt_periodLog = new DataTable("dt_periodLog");
sta_readLogByPeriod(dt_periodLog, dt1.Text, dt2.Text);
```

**Now you can use this data table in for loop to show in gridview**

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt_periodLog .Rows)
            {
                datagridview1.Rows.Add(row[0]);
            }
```